# Call Lua function from C++ using LuaBridge

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api, luabridge

I am having some trouble calling Lua functions from C++ using LuaBridge. The idea is that I want to call "Update" on the script on every game update in C++. The following code is what I have [found online](https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/using-lua-with-cpp-luabridge/):

```
LuaRef sumNumbers = getGlobal(L, "sumNumbers");
int result = sumNumbers(5, 4);
```

So in my case this would be:

```
LuaRef updateFunction = getGlobal(L, "Update");
updateFunction();
```

However, the `getGlobal` does not seem to exist in LuaBridge 2.0 (`luabridge` namespace). This is different from the `lua_getglobal`

I am wondering if this has been replaced by a different function call or if it has been deprecated out of the 2.0 version. I can of course use the normal C Lua approach, but I was wondering if this has been abstracted in LuaBridge (to make things easier)

Comment: I can't reproduce this and I'm using luabridge from the master branch on github. Did you try qualifying it, eg. `luabridge::getGlobal`?

Comment: Good catch! I pulled the latest release version from GitHub instead of the master branch. Thank you. Post your answer and I'll give you credit

Comment: Okie added an answer, glad to help ^_^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest source from the [**github project repository**](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge). When I tested this from luabridge's master branch, `luabridge::getGlobal` is present and working.